# How can I call DisplayFor from inside of a custom extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I am trying to write some `HtmlHelper` extension to clean up my views. I have a need to use `Html.DisplayFor()` to render my model. I write the following extension

```
public static MvcHtmlString MakeTableBodyTd(this HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metaData)
{
    var td = new TagBuilder("td");

    if (metaData != null)
    {
        var cssClassName = metaData.AdditionalValues.GetValueOrDefault("TextAlignment", "left");

        td.AddCssClass(cssClassName);

        var t = html.DisplayFor(x => metaData.Model, metaData.DataTypeName, new { Metadata = metaData }).ToHtmlString();

        td.InnerHtml = t;
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(td.ToString());
}
```

However, this extension is giving me this error

> 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no
>   extension method 'DisplayFor(...)' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?

I am able to use `@Html.DisplayFor(...)` in my views with no issues, but unable to use the in the extensions class.

I have added a reference to the following libraries

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

But still giving me the error.

The html has only the following methods available `html.Display()`, `html.DisplayForModel()`, `html.DisplayName()`, `html.DisplayNameForModel()` and `html.DisplayText()`

How can I use the `html.DisplayFor(...)` method inside my extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the the signature of the method to include `<TModel>` in order to use the `***For()` methods.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MakeTableBodyTd<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, ModelMetadata metaData)
{
    ....
}
```